# Rigid body physics based pulley in blender?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

Hi I want to make a simple physics based pulley with two rigid body objects, so that when the heavier object moves (via physics) it pulls the other object over the pulley. I don't need the 'rope' between the objects, just the physics of the pulley. Any help appreciated. [image]

Comment: There is no easy or simple way to do this as rigid bodies are "rigid" and will stay in only one shape.

Comment: That’s a shame, maybe adding a rope is the best method?

Comment: You can't do that due to how belnder sims work